# Custom url route for rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise

I'm new to rails and am wondering how to get the user to go to a specific url path when they submit this form instead of re-directing back to the homepage which is the default action. I'm using devise as well but I'm not sure if that changes anything (like I said I'm pretty new!). I tried adding  tags around the submit button and changing the form_for at the top but to no avail. Thanks in advance!

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>


  <div id="title">
    <p class="main-titles"><a href="/">The 100 Story Project</a></p>
  </div>

  <div id="nav">

    <div class="register_fields">
        <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, :placeholder => "Email Address" %></div>

    <div class="register_fields">
        <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", :placeholder => "Password" %></div>

    <div class="submit"><%= f.submit "→" %></div>

  </div>

  <div id="written" class="sticky">
    <div class="main-titles written-margin"><p>Written by</p><p class="written-name"></p></div>
  </div>

  <div id="yellow">
  </div>

  <div id="background">
    <div id="story-wrapper">
      <p></p>
    </div>

  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll be able to use devise [built-in helpers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-after-a-successful-sign-in-or-sign-out) to achieve this:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
Class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
       current_user_path
    end

    def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
       request.referrer
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this & the link! Knew there would be some documentation somewhere